# Can I combine built-in filters in a custom Flask jinja2 filter?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I'm trying to make a custom-filter in Flask, I am not sure if I can use custom filters with blueprints, so I just put it in my app config, because I can't use @app decorator in other files.

```
def configure_jinja2(app):
    urlize = app.jinja_env.filters['urlize']
    truncate = app.jinja_env.filters['truncate']
    @app.template_filter('myfilter')
    def myfilter(s, trim=False, trunc=255):
        s = urlize(s)
        if trim:
          s = truncate(s, trunc)
        return s
```

So I'm trying to combine 2 built-in jinja2 filters, to create a new custom filter that will also do other stuff.

This gives an error: **TypeError: do_urlize() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)**

What do I put in for eval_context?

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jinja2.filters.do_urlize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py#L406) is just a thin wrapper around [jinja2.utils.urlize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/utils.py#L263) which doesn't take an eval_context. The same seems to go for most other built-in filters that take an evaluation context, too.

Comment: yeah i noticed 
    from jinja2.utils import Markup, urlize
    from jinja2.filters import do_truncate